# Android all variables are reset when SMS is sent

Tags: java, android, sms

Hey I'm making an app in which I need to send a text message but every time I send the message the app opens again and all the variables are reset(I have tried to implement a system that save the variables but they still get reset), however it still sends the message. Why is it doing this, and how can I fix it; this is my code

```
public void sendSMS(String phono, String mes)
    {
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
        new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);
        SmsManager sm = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sm.sendTextMessage(phono, null, mes, pi, null);
    }
         //Button that uses method
  b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            phono = "personal phone number";
            if (phono.length() > 0 && mes.length() > 0)
                sendSMS(phono, mes);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Post the activity which uses this method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking the SMSManager to relaunch your app when the SMS is successfully sent.

From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html),

```
public void sendTextMessage (String destinationAddress, String scAddress, String text, PendingIntent sentIntent, PendingIntent deliveryIntent),
```

the `pi` in your code will be used as the `sentIntent`, which means when the SMS is sent out of the device, `SMSManager` will automatically trigger the intent.

If you don't want the SMS manager to relaunch your app again after the SMS is sent, just send a `null` in place of `pi`.

```
sm.sendTextMessage(phono, null, mes, null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `sm.sendTextMessage(phono, null, mes, pi, null);` with
`sm.sendTextMessage(phono, null, mes, null, null);`